# OpenCV cv::Mat displays empty gray images? Cant find the reason

Tags: image, opencv

I just want to display this "img1.jpg" image in a c++ project with using opencv libs for future processes, but it only displays an empty gray window. What is the reason of this. Is there a mistake in this code? please help!

Here is the code;

```
 Mat img1;
 char imagePath[256] = "img1.jpg";
 img1 = imread(imagePath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
 namedWindow("result", 1);
 imshow("result", img1);
```

Thanks...

Comment: Just to provide more detail I had the same problem when using OpenCV 2.3.1 and Visual Studio 2008 (VC90), I had to insert a waitKey(1) for it to work.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved putting `waitKey(1);` after `imshow()`. The OpenCV documentation explains why:

> This function is the only method in HighGUI that can fetch and handle
>   events, so it needs to be called periodically for normal event
>   processing, unless HighGUI is used within some environment that takes
>   care of event processing.

Comment: This also helped me - I recommend marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: I agree, it works. I don't fully understand the reason, but it was sweet relief after fearing I had to implement/install some codecs!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @b_froz.
For more detials about this issue,you can refer to: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow

> Note This function should be followed by waitKey function which displays the image for specified milliseconds. Otherwise, it won’t display the image. For example, waitKey(0) will display the window infinitely until any keypress (it is suitable for image display). waitKey(25) will display a frame for 25 ms, after which display will be automatically closed. (If you put it in a loop to read videos, it will display the video frame-by-frame)

So,not only `waitkey(1)`could be put after `imshow()`,but also `waitkey(0)` or `waitkey(other integers)`.Here is the explanation of the function `waitkey()` : http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing the correct library ?
This is other very easy way to load one image:

```
#define CV_NO_BACKWARD_COMPATIBILITY
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <math.h>
main(){
IplImage* img  = cvLoadImage("yourPicture.jpg");
cvNamedWindow("Original", 1);
cvShowImage("Original", img);
}
```

I think you have openCV correctly installed, so yo can type this (Ubuntu):
g++ NameOfYourProgram.cpp -o Sample -I/usr/local/include/opencv/ -L/usr/local/lib -lcv -lhighgui ./sample

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is due to the type of your `Mat img1`. When you load your image with the flag `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE`, the type of your `Mat` is 0 (`CV_8UC1`), and the function `imshow()` is not able to show the image correctly.
You can solve this, converting your `Mat` to type 16 (`CV_8UC3`):

```
img1.convertTo(img1,CV_8UC3);
```

and then show it with `imshow()`:

```
imshow("result", img1);
```

I hope this help.