# OpenCV : why "Gray window" always generate?

Tags: c++, opencv

I already See  that page :: "[OpenCV cv::Mat displays empty gray images? Cant find the reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845460/opencv-cvmat-displays-empty-gray-images-cant-find-the-reason)"

In my code, I want to show some image.

```
cv::Mat img;
img = cv::imread("stop.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
cv::imshow("EXAM", img);
cv::waitKey(0);
cv::destroyWindow("EXAM");
```

but it code is generate Just Gray window. and Window size is same input image.

Is may occur 'not installed jpeg codec'. but it situation has doubtful point.

```
cv::Mat img;
img = cv::imread("stop.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
cv::namedWindow("EXAM",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);  // <<-- added
cv::imshow("EXAM", img);
cv::waitKey(0);
cv::destroyWindow("EXAM");
```

when starting that code, 'stop.jpg' image are clearly open.

**+ also generate Damn Gray window.**

I don't, really don't understand. i don't want generate Gray window.

because if setting eventlistener in image Window, don't work at image window.

instead listener works in "Gray Window".

If i can't remove Gray Window, i want working eventlistener in image window. not Gray Window.

Please Help.

Comment: Maybe try a different image - say a PNG image? Maybe try checking for errors and return values? Maybe show your complete code as StackOverflow requires?

Comment: i just exclude include code. / nothing errors. / diff image also make gray window : <

Comment: Your code cannot be compiled as it is, so it is incomplete. Your code doesn't check the error values, so it's not surprising there are no errors. Did you check a different format image?

Comment: Incomplete? Um... ok i will check your opnions. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved.

It problem is Version Issue. (3.4.1)